# Apache Camel: How to read a multi-line XML response using netty4:tcp

Tags: netty

Only the XML declaration is being returned since it is textline, but without textline it also does not work. Isn't there already a decode codec for this?

The following is what is being used to send the message:

```
.recipientList(simple("netty4:tcp://$simple{property.server}:{{server.port}}?textline=true&sync=true"))
```

but only the first line of the XML response containing the XML declaration statement is being returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```